# <happi._core.FieldFactory object at 0x17c0490>

Tags: python

I am trying to extract the data values using the following python script:

```
import happi
import math
import numpy
S = happi.Open(results_path='/mnt/iusers01/fatpou01/phy01/v55735sk/scratch/SIM', show=True, reference_angular_frequency_SI=None, verbose=True)
print(S.namelist.Main.simulation_time)   # print the timestep
print(S.namelist.Main.geometry)   # print the simulation dimensions
species = S.namelist.Species["electron"]
print("species "+species.name+" has mass "+str(species.mass))
print(S.Field)
print(S.Probe)
print(S.Scalar)
Diag = S.Field(0., "Ex")
Diag = S.Scalar("Utot")
print(S.namelist.LaserPlanar1D)
```

and getting in the output:

```
<happi._core.FieldFactory object at 0x2b3103e40490>
<happi._core.ProbeFactory object at 0x29ed650>
<happi._core.ScalarFactory object at 0x2beaa10>
<function LaserPlanar1D at 0x27807d0>
```

What does mean by object at ---- ?
Why I don't get the value in output file? please help me

Answer (score 0):

For these:

> <happi._core.FieldFactory object at 0x2b3103e40490>

> <happi._core.ProbeFactory object at 0x29ed650>

> <happi._core.ScalarFactory object at 0x2beaa10>

It seems happi._core.FieldFactory, happi._core.ProbeFactory, and happi._core.ScalarFactory aren't overriding the str() function.

For this:

> <function LaserPlanar1D at 0x27807d0>

LaserPlanar1D is a function and must be called to get something resembling output.

The hex locations refer to the output of the [**repr** function](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) and, according to the documentation is information-rich and unambiguous.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to override the str() function?

Comment: Not unless you provide me with an example of what you want it to give?

Comment: I have .h5 file there are parameter and name list inside it. I want to extract dat from it and I want plot it ? The script I used in my qusetion? In namelist: Scalar, Probe, Laser, Species etc.